# Left div and footer as positon-fixed are not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to fix left div and footer as position fixed and on scroll left dive and right div content should scroll accordingly, in my case my left div and footer got fixed but on scroll my left div content is not scrolling up and down as per image attached here..

I don't want to give overflow-y: auto to sidebar it should scroll on windows scroll, and footer should be always be fixed in bottom only.

I am also attaching my working screenshot for reference.

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#sidebar {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#main-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

#sidebar .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #main-wrapper {
    float: right;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  #main-wrapper {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    position: static;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 300px;
    border-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 mb20"> <img class="profile-image" src="primage.png"> </div>
      <h3>General Information</h3>
      <ul class="profile-details">
        <li>
          <div><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i> Party Name</div> Congress </li>
        <li>
          <div><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>position</div> Party President </li>
        <li>
          <div><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>Winner</div> Rank No.1 </li>
      </ul>
      <h3>Contact Information</h3>
      <ul class="profile-details">
        <li>
          <div><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> phone</div> +91 022 28106240 </li>
        <li>
          <div><i class="fa fa-tablet"></i> mobile phone</div> +91 9819046204 </li>
        <li>
          <div><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> e-mail</div> Rahul@rediffmail.com </li>
        <li>
          <div><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>current address</div> B-301,Akansha Tower
          <br> Naya Nagar, Mira Road - E
          <br> Dist. Thane - 401107. </li>
        <li>
          <div><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>permanent address</div> B-301,Akansha Tower
          <br> Naya Nagar, Mira Road - E
          <br> Dist. Thane - 401107. </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main-wrapper" class="col-lg-10 col-md-6 col-xs-12 pull-right">
  <div id="main">
    <div class="col-lg-12"> ht ht </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 footer"> ht ht </div>
```

Please find herewith image for working reference.

[image]

Comment: there is no image link

Comment: Can u create a fiddle with all this

Answer (score 0):

HTML -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js">
    </script>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-xs-12" id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div id="sidebar">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 mb20">
                    <img class="profile-image" src="primage.png">
                    </img>
                </div>
                <h3>
                    General Information
                </h3>
                <ul class="profile-details">
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <i class="fa fa-building-o">
                            </i>
                            Party Name
                        </div>
                        Congress
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <i class="fa fa-briefcase">
                            </i>
                            position
                        </div>
                        Party President
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <i class="fa fa-briefcase">
                            </i>
                            Winner
                        </div>
                        Rank No.1
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <h3>
                    Contact Information
                </h3>
                <ul class="profile-details">
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <i class="fa fa-phone">
                            </i>
                            phone
                        </div>
                        +91 022 28106240
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <i class="fa fa-tablet">
                            </i>
                            mobile phone
                        </div>
                        +91 9819046204
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope">
                            </i>
                            e-mail
                        </div>
                        Rahul@rediffmail.com
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker">
                            </i>
                            current address
                        </div>
                        B-301,Akansha Tower
                        <br>
                            Naya Nagar, Mira Road - E
                            <br>
                                Dist. Thane - 401107.
                            </br>
                        </br>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker">
                            </i>
                            permanent address
                        </div>
                        B-301,Akansha Tower
                        <br>
                            Naya Nagar, Mira Road - E
                            <br>
                                Dist. Thane - 401107.
                            </br>
                        </br>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-6 col-xs-12 pull-right" id="main-wrapper">
            <div id="main">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    ht ht
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 footer">
            ht ht
        </div>
    </div>
</link>
```

CSS -

```
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#sidebar {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#main-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

#sidebar .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #main-wrapper {
    float: right;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  #main-wrapper {
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    position: static;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 300px;
    border-right: 0;
  }
}
```

I have corrected your mistake, this is working code.What you did wrong was you closed #wrapper div before col-10 hence bootstrap wasn't getting implemented correctly.